# Rendering multiple templates with web.py

Tags: python, linux, frameworks, web.py

Ive recently gotten into Webdesign in Python, I've tried multiple frameworks but web.py seems to be my favorite except for one problem. I cant seem to figure out how to make multiple pages with multiple templates....

here is my code so far:

```
import web

urls = (

'/', 'index', '/login/', 'login'


)

app = web.application(urls, globals())
render = web.template.render('templates/')

class index():
    def GET(self):
        return render.index()
class login():
    def GET(self):
        return render.login()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I get an error when I try to go to the login page :/

Comment: You have a `login.html` in the `templates/` directory, correct?

Comment: Yes, index.html loads its just when I try to go to login.html

Comment: Are you going to `http://.../login` or `http://.../login/`? (note the trailing slash)

Comment: /login/ but I have tried both.

Comment: That's strange, because it works for me.

Comment: Would you mind showing me your code?

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code and added dummy templates (`index` in `templates/index.html` and `login` in `templates/login.html`).

Comment: Well, thats strange, when I use my code I get "not found"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your url mapping:

```
urls = (
    '/', 'index', 
    '/login/?', 'login',
)
```

`/login/?` will work for `/login` and `/login/` url paths.

It will be better if you show an exception that you get.

Comment: Oh my god I love you so much! You dont even know how long this has been bothering me